# Rancher slow performance deploying new docker image

Tags: docker, rancher

I'm simply using the rancher CLI to redeploy a new Docker image for an existing app I already have in rancher. Any time I do this it takes 10-20 minutes. Why would it take that long for such a simple image? How can I best troubleshoot this?

It seems like it takes forever to pull the image from our Artifactory registry, but the latency between the servers is only 64ms.

Here's the nginx docker image I'm trying to deploy:

```
# Builds a Docker to deliver dist/
FROM nginx:stable

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Copy SSL Cert/Key
COPY ssl/partner-portal.crt /etc/ssl/certs
COPY ssl/partner-portal.key /etc/ssl/private

# Copy main website
COPY dist/ /etc/nginx/html
```

Comment: What is the size of the image after building? I would test a manual pull from one of the hosts registered to the rancher environment you are pulling to:

`rancher --host HOSTID docker pull my/image`

Comment: It only had 1GB RAM on a VM and I had everything on one node. Once I upped memory to 4GB and another CPU, I was good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In spite of the docs saying you can run Rancher on 1GB, it quickly causes latency issues. I recommend at least 2GB if not more, especially if you plan to run single node with everything running on it.